# MS Access File Size

Tags: ms-access

I know there is no specific answer for this but I am hoping I can get a roundabout answer. MS Access technically has no size limit due to linking files and such but I have a MS Access DB that I would like to keep all together of which I will be adding nearly 80,000 records to on a monthly basis. My business operates heavily in the summer season so this will be for about 4 months. Then in the rest of the months, we will be adding about 30,000 records to. What do you think the life of this system will be? Thanks for any help!

Kevin

MS Access 2016

Comment: I am a big fan of Access, but it may be time to look at a different back-end db. Note that a record can be any size, so it is impossible to judge from your question.

Comment: @Fionnuala is right, though 0.5 mio. "normal" records should pose no problem. The question is rather for how many years? And don't consider having separate backend files for each year or old data; such setups only cause troubles. So I would consider expandable backend engines like MySQL or - at a cost - SQL Server.

Comment: I am very fluent in SQL server and would love to use it, however it does not work with the current business so that's why I chose Access. I'm trying to determine how many years I can expect to get out of the system given most records will be numbers or dates with a max of 6 fields in each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a simgle table with 6 fields and added 80,000 records.  I am looking at 6,440KB.  Now, with a compact and repair, it's 6,140KB.  Adding records will fragment the DB over time, so you will have to keep doing C&R over and over.  Anyway, let's say you enter around 8,000KB per month, and Access can grow to around 2GB, but you will probably see some weird things happening if you actually get close to that.  So, 2GB = 2,000,000KB and 2,000,000/8000 = 250 months and 250/12 = 20.8 years.